# How to get return value in timer

Tags: python, python-3.x, timer

i made simple timer 
this timer has two function
1.countdown 2. stopwatch

btw i want to use timer in game
ex) countdown stop > game finish

So i want return value in timer.. 
but i can't
plz help me :)

```py
import time
import threading
count = 0

def start_timer(count):
    print(count)
    count -= 1
    timer = threading.Timer(1, start_timer, args=[count])
    timer.start()

    if count == 0:
        print("game start!")
        timer.cancel()

def stop_watch():
        now = time.time()
        check = input("press button\n")
        stop = time.time()
        print("time : %0.3f" % (stop - now))
```

i can't get return value

Comment: Use ```yield``` instead of return.

Comment: how to use yield? can you give me some example ?? sry

Comment: Assume you want to use return , where would you put it? Put the return statement there and then replace it with yield.